# What's the name of this hinge?

Tags: joinery, wood

I am planning to build a motorized bed. I am still in the researching phase so I went to a bedroom shop in my city. In the shop I saw this hinge, or at least I believe it´s called a hinge. I have been researching it for 2 days now and I can't seem to figure out the name or type of hinge they used for this particular joint.

The only type of hinge I found similar was the Knife hinge, but that isn't quite what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know for sure, but I think a key search term for you might be "flat pivot hinge".

Comment: FYI you don't *need* this exact hinge type. Many hinges are interchangeable with others since they do the same basic job. Anyway, I found some search terms that might help you find something that will work for you, "adjustable bed hinge" and "recliner hinge".